# how to show different fragment and XML in a tab of bottom navigation menu using navigation controller component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using  navigation controller components and I have 4 tabs menu in my bottom navigation view. 
I want to set two different fragments (and different xml layout) for the profile tab menu (menu in index 3), so if the user is verified then I will show UI A, and otherwise I will show UI B

so how to dynamically change the fragment and UI like that ?

the user data will be fetched from home fragment (home tab menu - menu index 0). and then saved in the local storage. so I want when the user tab index 3 (profile), it will show different UI according to user status, verified or not

or do you have a better approach to achieve similar behaviour ?

[image]

here is my main activity code to set up the bottom navigation view

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {

    private lateinit var navController : NavController
    lateinit var generalToolbar : Toolbar
    lateinit var bottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setUpViewDeclaration()
        setupBottomNavMenu()
        setupActionBar()


        // Add Listeners
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)



    }



    private fun setUpViewDeclaration() {

        generalToolbar = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.include_toolbar_general).findViewById(R.id.toolbar_general)
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)

    }

    private fun setupBottomNavMenu() {
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    private fun setupActionBar() {

        // set up top hierarchy destination
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.destination_home,
            R.id.destination_search,
            R.id.destination_user_control,
            R.id.destination_create_event)
        )

        setSupportActionBar(generalToolbar)
        generalToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)



    }
```

and here is the XML of my bottom navigation view menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/destination_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/home" />

    <item
            android:id="@+id/destination_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="@string/search" />

    <item
            android:id="@+id/destination_create_event"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline"
            android:title="@string/createEvent" />

    <item
            android:id="@+id/destination_user_control"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:title="@string/profile" />




</menu>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't your `destination_user_control` fragment just change itself based on what type of profile the user has?

Comment: @ianhanniballake sir I am sorry, I am new in android development, I don't understand, what do you mean by 'fragment just change itself' ? really need your help :)

Comment: @ianhanniballake could you please help me to at least give a hint, sir ?